# Remove disk image from the disk list

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

In Disk Utility I see two disk images (Flash Updates)

[image]

But I cannot find where the image file could be.

On the console with `diskutil` I see

```
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +16.9 MB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            16.9 MB    disk2s2
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +17.2 MB    disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            17.1 MB    disk4s2
```

And with `diskutil info`

```
   Device Identifier:        disk4
   Device Node:              /dev/disk4
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk4
   Device / Media Name:      Apple UDIF read-only compressed (bzip2) Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      Apple_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               17.2 MB (17170432 Bytes) (exactly 33536 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          Yes
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Yes
   Media Removal:            Software-Activated

   Virtual:                  Yes
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Is there a way to know where these images are on my disk?

Comment: Does clicking on the actual disk image (Apple UDIF...) show where it's at? On the old disk utility, it would be there.

Comment: The eject command works. I had 2 of these relics for some time.

Comment: Hi, the question is not on how to eject them but where the dmg files are on the disk.

Comment: Try selecting the disk image icon rather than the unmounted volume icon (which is what the image above shows). At least in previous versions of Disk Utility, that shows info about the disk image file (.dmg). You can also right click on the disk image icon and choose Eject. Not sure if that still holds true for El Capitan or not...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hdiutil` will show information about all mounted DMGs:

```
hwd@hwds-iMac:~$ hdiutil info  
framework       : 415
driver          : 10.11v415
================================================
image-path      : /Users/hwd/Downloads/mountedImageOne.dmg
image-alias     : /Users/hwd/Downloads/mountedImageOne.dmg
shadow-path     : <none>
icon-path       : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework    /Resources/CDiskImage.icns
image-type      : UDIF, nur Lesen, komprimiert (bzip2)
system-image    : false
blockcount      : 22528
blocksize       : 512
writeable       : false
autodiskmount   : TRUE
removable       : TRUE
image-encrypted : false
mounting user   : hwd
mounting mode   : <unknown>
process ID      : 5376
/dev/disk2      Apple_partition_scheme  
/dev/disk2s1    Apple_partition_map 
/dev/disk2s2    Apple_HFS   /Volumes/mountedImageOne
================================================
image-path      : /Users/hwd/Downloads/mountedImageTwo.dmg
image-alias     : /Users/hwd/Downloads/mountedImageTwo.dmg
shadow-path     : <none>
icon-path       : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/CDiskImage.icns
image-type      : UDIF, nur Lesen, komprimiert (zlib)
system-image    : false
blockcount      : 20480
blocksize       : 512
writeable       : false
autodiskmount   : TRUE
removable       : TRUE
image-encrypted : false
mounting user   : hwd
mounting mode   : <unknown>
process ID      : 5416
/dev/disk3      GUID_partition_scheme   
/dev/disk3s1    48465300-0000-AAAA-AAAA-000000000000    /Volumes/mountedImageTwo
```

Answer (score 7):

The question is actually "How to remove...".

It can be ejected by using the device path

`diskutil eject /dev/disk4`

Substitute `disk4` for whichever disk is offensive.

Comment: Thanks John2095 that worked for me on my MacBookPro running El Capitan.
Just encase people have not done this before this what to do - open the Macintosh HD/Applications/Utilities/TERMINAL.APP - then just
type diskutil eject /devdisk2 substitute disk2 for whichever disk you want to eject like John2095 said.

Answer (score 3):

Mount them through Disk Utility and you will see them in Finder where you can just unmount them by clicking on the eject icon in the sidebar next to their names (in Finder) and they will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't actually answer the question that was asked.